# Different prices on category and product page

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.8.1 and have a strange issue. I have set up a store with 0% TAX. There is a discount on certain products for business customers (certain customer group). The price is 8.20 instead of 14.95.
The discount price shows corrcectly everywhere except for the category list and also the related products column. There is shows 7.00?

Of course I tried reindexing but with no result.

I am totally in the dark zbout how this is possible.

Does anybody have experience with this or a hint where to search?

Thank you,

Marcel

Comment: are all sharing the same price.phtml?

Comment: Yes they do. It is also that not all products are affected and there does not seem to be a pattern. My guess is that it could have something to do with cache, although I refreshed that already.